# How to write an AJAX call without passing any data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to pass an AJAX call without passing any data. What is the correct way I am getting error 500. I have tried the following code:

```
function loaddata(){
    $.ajax({
           url: 'ListCustomer',
           data: {

           },
           error: function(xhr, statusText, err) {
             alert("error"+xhr.status);
           },

           success: function(data) {
             alert(data);
           },
           type: 'GET'
        });
}
```

I am using spring mvc.method is calling but has an error.

Comment: remove `data:` completely... though i doubt that's your problem.

Comment: Isn't it simply a problem in your url ? 
Use '/ListCustomer' instead of 'ListCustomer'

Comment: when apply '/ListCustomer'  there's another error no 404.completetly removed data but still as same

Answer (score 10):

You remove the data, by removing the `data:{},`

```
           $.ajax({
           url: 'ListCustomer',
           error: function(xhr, statusText, err) {
             alert("error"+xhr.status);
           },

           success: function(data) {
             alert(data);
           },
           type: 'GET'
        });
```

But `500` is an internal server error. Which means it's an error on the server. Your question, therefore, shouldn't be geared around what you're doing on the client - until you've found out what the error on the server is. Otherwise you're just poking around in the dark until you pass it the parameters it needs, that's *if* the server error is even due to a parameter issue.

If the server is yours, check the logs, debug it, whatever you have to do to find out what that exception is.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to pass an AJAX call without passing any data

With jQuery `$.get()`:

```
$.get('ListCustomer',function(resp){
  console.log('response from server', resp);
}).fail(function(){
  console.log('something went wrong!');
});
```

There is also `$.getJSON()` and `$.post()`, perhaps usage varies on your requirement.

> I am getting error 500

This has nothing to do with client script, rather you must check the server logs for detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an AJAX without passing any data you have to omit not only the `data` attribute, but also the `dataType` attribute if you have define it, so:

Even if you omit the `data` attribute, **this won't work**, even if you omit the `data` attribute:

```
$.ajax(
    {
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'ListCustomer',
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, statusText, err) {
        alert("error"+xhr.status);
      }
    });
```

**This will work:**

```
$.ajax(
    {
      type: "GET",
      url: 'ListCustomer',
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, statusText, err) {
        alert("error"+xhr.status);
      }
    });
```